# Changing Visual style of a MFC application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have an MFC based application which looks too old, maybe the theme is Native windows. I know that while creating a new MFC application, there is option to select different visual styles.

I want to select different Visual style now, maybe Windows 7. How can I do it?

Edit 1: The application is written in Visual Studio 2005. Hence the look and feel is too old. I have migrated it to Visual Studio 2015 but still the look is same.

Comment: See the examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983962(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you're running on Windows 7, a "native" style would look the same as a "Windows 7" style. What does it mean that the application "looks too old"? That isn't a thing. MFC's built-in themes are ugly and hackish. Function is more important than form anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray The code was written in VS 2005. I am using it on VS 2015 (Windows 7).

Comment: You are probably looking for [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4987/Using-Windows-XP-Styles-in-your-MFC-WIN-Applicat)

Comment: Windows 8 has been around for almost 5 years. The default Windows 7 UI theme is starting to look really dated. Besides, an MFC application should simply use the standard theme, enable Visual Styles, and respect the user's choice of what they find visually pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

In stdafx.h there is some code:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

are you sure if is working ? If the project aren't UNICODE, just comment #ifdef _UNICODE (and his pair #endif) in order to have visual style activated ...