# Windows 10 look and feel for VS2019 apps

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I developed a simple MFC application (dialog based) with Visual Studio 2019 in C++ (64 bits). It works perfect but has a poor look, like an old version of Windows, I can't make it look like a Windows 10 app.
I was using Visual Studio 2010 before and I could add a manifest file that I referenced in the .rc resource file, but this does not work anymore with VS2019.
How can I have my app with the nice Windows 10 look and feel?

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736105/changing-visual-style-of-a-mfc-application
As my app does not use UNICODE, this part was ignored. I commented the #ifdef and everything now works fine.

Comment: The correct solution would be to switch your app to [Unicode mode](https://vcpptips.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/how-to-convert-a-ansimb-project-into-a-unicode/). There are many problems with common controls in multi-byte mode.